# Many to Many Cardinal Direction Database Scheme Design

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, schema

I'm fairly new to database design and could use some advice on how to setup a schema for a learning project. The idea is like text based adventure games like Zork.

Take a Room database table:

```
class Room(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(512))

    north = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'))
    east = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'))
    west = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'))
    south = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id'))
```

When the user is in a room they can go south, north etc. The rooms are linked together. I feel like having the foreign keys be a part of the table is the wrong way to go about this. I'm using postgres and sqlalchemy. I feel like there is a way of designing these links without having to manually manage if a room gets removed from the database etc.

```
links_table = db.Table('directions',
    db.Column('north_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id')),
    db.Column('west_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id')),
    db.Column('east_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id')),
    db.Column('south_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id')))
```

Would something like this be a step in the right direction? Or do I need a table of north_to_south, south_to_north?

```
 north_to_south = db.Table('north_to_south',
    db.Column('north_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id')),
    db.Column('south_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('room.id')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if an SQL DB is the right tool for the job of storing such a map, but you're on the right track in that the directions could be stored in an [association table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), or in SQLAlchemy terms, using the [association object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) pattern. You could make your model even more flexible by making the association table such as `(src_id, dst_id, dir)`:

```
class Direction(db.Model):
    # Let the DB cascades remove directions, if a room is deleted.
    src_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('room.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                       primary_key=True)
    dst_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('room.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                       primary_key=True)
    # A point for further normalization, create a table for enumerating
    # direction labels.
    dir = db.Column(db.String(16), primary_key=True)

    # Since this model has multiple foreign keys referencing the same
    # target model, the relationships must be told which one to use.
    src = db.relationship('Room', foreign_keys=[src_id],
                          back_populates='directions')
    dst = db.relationship('Room', foreign_keys=[dst_id])
```

This would also allow you to use another nice SQLAlchemy feature: [mapping a collection of related objects as a dictionary](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dictionary-collections):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection

class Room(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(512))

    directions = db.relationship(
        'Direction', collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('dir'),
        foreign_keys='[Direction.src_id]', passive_deletes=True,
        back_populates='src')
```

Populating the directions is a bit of a chore:

```
In [33]: r1 = Room(title='r1')

In [34]: r2 = Room(title='r2')

In [35]: r3 = Room(title='r3')

In [36]: r4 = Room(title='r4')

In [37]: r5 = Room(title='r5')

In [39]: for dir_, dst in zip(['north', 'east', 'south', 'west'],
    ...:                      [r2, r3, r4, r5]):
    ...:     r1.directions[dir_] = Direction(dir=dir_, dst=dst)
    ...:     

In [40]: db.session.add(r1)

In [41]: db.session.commit()
```

Note the slight redundancy in that you have to both use the direction as the key and pass it to `Direction` constructor. Ideally you'd not have to deal with `Direction` at all. This can be achieved using an [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Room(db.Model):
    ...
    dirs = association_proxy(
        'directions', 'dst',
        creator=lambda dir_, dst: Direction(dir=dir_, dst=dst))
```

After which it is easier to add directions:

```
In [87]: r6 = Room(title='r6')

In [88]: r2.dirs['up'] = r6
```

This makes it easy to access directions given a variable:

```
In [79]: where_to = input()
west

In [80]: r1.dirs[where_to]
Out[80]: <__main__.Room at 0x7fa652e4a320>
```